# Android - webview : are the ressources loaded?

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way to know when all the ressources of a web page are loaded in a webview? The callback onPageFinished seems to fire when the base code of the page is loaded, not when all the images, video, are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can override shouldInterceptRequest method of [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

Comment: This function tells me when the webview starts loading a ressource, not when the loading has ended. Am I wrong ?